# How to view print messages in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift

How can I see the messages being printed at runtime in Xcode?

For example the following line:

```
print("Testing")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Press ⇧⌘Y or choose View > Debug Area > Show Debug Area to show the console output (or ⇧⌘C / Activate Console). Usually, this window will open automatically when your program produces output (this is controlled by the Behaviors section of Xcode's Preferences).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

XCode 11 + SwiftUI Users having the same issue, the answer is that you need to right-click the play button in the preview window to turn on `debug preview`! Assuming that you have the `debug area active` (view > debug area > activate console), as seen in:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, have Xcode 13 running, right-clicking on the play button doesn't do anything. Definitely not getting my console output.